# Prove that $x \in c=\{x=(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty \in l^\infty: \exists \lim_{k \to +\infty} x_k \in \mathbb{C}\}$ and $x_n \in c, x_n \to (x_k)_{k=1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

**I am working on this problem**
Let $c=\{x=(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty \in l^\infty: \exists \lim_{k \to +\infty} x_k \in \mathbb{C}\}$, let $x_n \in c, x_n \to (x_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ in the sup norm (that is in $l^{\infty})$. Prove that $x \in c$.

**My try:**

Since $x_n \in C : \lim_{k \to +\infty} x_{n,k}=l_n \in \mathbb{C}$ that is  $ \forall \varepsilon > 0, |x_{n,k}-l_n|< \varepsilon \;\forall k>K_{\varepsilon}(n) ....(\theta)$

Since  $x_n \to x :$ for $\varepsilon > 0 $ $|x_{n,k}-x_k| \leq ||x_n-x||_{\infty} <\varepsilon \;\forall n> N_{\varepsilon }....(\beta)$

Taking the limit for $k \to \infty$:$$\left|\lim_{k \to +\infty}x_{n,k}-\lim_{k \to +\infty}x_k\right| \leq \varepsilon $$  $$ \left|l_n-\lim_{k \to +\infty}x_k\right| \leq \varepsilon$$
which means that, calling $l :=\lim_{k \to +\infty}x_k...(\zeta)$, $$ |l_n-l| \leq \varepsilon...(\gamma)$$ so that $$l :=\lim_{n \to +\infty}l_n$$

then $|x_k -l|=|x_k-x_{n,k}+x_{n,k}-l_n+l_n-l|\leq |x_k-x_{n,k}|+|x_{n,k}-l_n|+|l_n-l|$

and using $(\theta),(\beta)$ and $(\gamma)$:
$$|x_k -l|<3\varepsilon, \text{for } k> K(N_{\varepsilon})$$ which proves that  $x_k \to l$ and so $x \in c$.

**I think it is wrong** because at $(\zeta)$,I am defining $\lim_{k \to +\infty}x_k =l$, which is precisely what I wanted to prove. Can someone tell me if this or somewhere else is wrong and help me fixed it?

Comment: Are you trying to prove the norms space $(c,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$—the space of convergent sequences—is a complete (that is,  $(c,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is a Banach space?)

Comment: @Jack LeGrüß I haven't realized that, but yeah it looks like that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly identified the mistake, we have to first prove that $(l_n)_n$ converges and then that $(x_k)_k$ converges to $\lim_{n\to\infty} l_n$.

To prove this, we can show that $(l_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Pick $\varepsilon > 0$. Sequence $(x_n)_n$ is converges in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ so it is in particular Cauchy. Therefore we can pick $n_0 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $m,n \ge n_0 \implies \|x_m-x_n\|_\infty \le \frac\varepsilon3$.

Now for $m,n\ge n_0$ pick an index $k \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $|x_m(k)-l_m|, |x_n(k)-l_n|\le\frac\varepsilon3$. Then
$$|l_m-l_n| \le |l_m-x_m(k)| + \underbrace{|x_m(k)-x_n(k)|}_{\le \|x_m-x_n\|_\infty} + |x_n(k)-l_n| \le \frac\varepsilon3+\frac\varepsilon3+\frac\varepsilon3=\varepsilon.$$

Hence $(l_n)_n$ converges to some $l \in \Bbb{C}$.

Now it remains to prove that $(x_k)_k$ converges to $l$, which you already did in the second part of your proof.

Comment: So If I understand correctly since I don't know that x_k converges to proceed as I mistakenly tried to, the workaround is to prove Cauchyness because for that I don't need to deal with the limit, but only with a couple of elements of the sequence

Comment: @mathlover Yes, precisely.